# About cardinality of normal subgroup of finite non abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non abelian group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ . What is $o(H)$?

I think $O(H) = O(G)/2$

Correct me if i m wrong

Comment: If what you think were true and taking into account Lagrange's Theorem, then *all* the groups of odd order would be simple (i.e., without normal non-trivial subgroups)...do you think this is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{e\}$ is always a normal subgroup of $G$, no matter what $G$ is, and $H=G$ is also always a normal subgroup. So, certainly one can't conclude from the normality of $H$ in $G$ that the order of $H$ is half the order of $G$.

What is true is that for any group $G$, finite or not, any subgroup $H$ of index $2$ (so in particular if $G$ is finite and $H$ contains half the elements of $G$), then $H$ is normal. The other implication, as noted, is in general false. There are many many normal subgroups not of index two.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on $H$. It is always true that $O(H)|O(G)$, but it doesn't have to be $2$.
For example, take any non-abelian group $G_1$ and any group $G_2$ and denote $G=G_1\times G_2$ and $H=G_1$ then $H$ is normal in $G$, but $O(G)/O(H)=O(G_2)$.